# Binary Search Tree in C.

Tags: c

I am confused that what mistake i am doing. Why isn't it printing the tree in preorder, postorder and inorder. I have written my questions beside the line of code where i am confused. Plus i don't understand how to relate to structs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct BST_{
    int data;
    struct BST_ *lchild, *rchild, *parent;
}BST;

typedef struct BiTree_{
    int size;
    BST *root;  // is it possible to relate this root with the pointer parent of type BST? i yes then how?
}BiTree;;
BST *temp;
BST *createNode(int data){
    BST *new_ele;
    new_ele=(BST*)malloc(sizeof(BST));
    new_ele->data=data;
    new_ele->lchild=NULL;
    new_ele->rchild=NULL;
    new_ele->parent=NULL;
    return new_ele;
    }

void insertNode(BST *temp,BST *r,int data){
    if(temp==NULL){
            temp=createNode(data);
         }

    else if(temp->data >= r->data){
            if(r->rchild==NULL){
                r->rchild=temp;
            }
            else{
                insertNode(r->rchild,temp,data);
            }
    }
    else if(temp->data <= r->data){
            if(r->lchild==NULL){
                r->lchild=temp; 
            }
            else{
                insertNode(r->lchild,temp,data);    
                            }
    }
//  return r->data;  //why cann't i do this?
}

void preorder(BST *r){
    if(r!=NULL){
        printf("%d",r->data);
        preorder(r->lchild);
        preorder(r->rchild);
    }
}
void inorder(BST *c){
    if(c!=NULL){

        inorder(c->lchild);
        printf("%d",c->data);
        inorder(c->rchild);
    }
}
void postorder(BST *r){
    if(r!=NULL){
        postorder(r->lchild);
        postorder(r->rchild);
        printf("%d",r->data);
    }
}
void delet(BST *r){
    if(r!=NULL){
        free(r);
    }
}
void main(){
    BST *new_node,*r=NULL;
    BiTree *search;
    search=malloc(sizeof(BiTree));
    search->root=NULL;
    search->size=0;
    int i,a,n,data;
    printf("Enter the number of element to be inserted\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter the data\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            scanf("%d",&data);


            insertNode(temp,r,data);
            //  printf("Enter the data %d\n",r->data);  // unable to print this

            search->size++;
            }
    printf("size is %d\n",search->size);

    preorder(r);//  why cann't i print the data of r. r is the root of the tree.
    postorder(r);
    inorder(r);
    delet(r);

}
```

Comment: Please describe the behaviour of your program more precisely by providing the input, the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: `r` is never not NULL.

Comment: It just ask for inputs and give the size. where i want to print the tree in preorder, postorder and inorder and then delete it. I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

- // is it possible to relate this root with the pointer parent of type BST? i yes then how?*

Please rephrase this question

- //  return r->data;  //why cann't i do this?

The signature of the function `void insertNode(BST *temp,BST *r,int data){` is saying that nothing should be returned. Change this

- printf("Enter the data %d\n",r->data);  // unable to print this

In the function `r` is initialised to `NULL` and nothing in the function changes this

- why cann't i print the data of r. r is the root of the tree.

See the point above

Answer (score 1):

`temp` is not set to NULL, and I think if its not `NULL`, it is going to have garbage in it. 
With this your `insertNode()` function will not allocate memory and all the code inside this function is entirely dependent on the garbage value of temp.

Comment: sorry for responding late, it may not work because of other issues. But this initialization was necessary. Have you tried to put this under debugger ? If not, let me know - I will do it.